# How to take multiple inputs (integer and string) for a program with different conditions

Tags: c

I tried to implement this code in different ways but it always go to break(last condition), so I don't know what the problem is.

It is supposed to read the `integer` input and the `on/off` input and then print the correct result

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    printf("start");
    int c;
    char ch;
    int light_id = 1;
    //char on_off_str;
    while (light_id > 0) {

      printf("Enter number and on/off_str:\n");
      //c = getchar();
      //ch = getchar();


      if (c = getchar() == 1) {
        if (ch = getchar() == 'on')  {
          printf("1 and on");
    }
      if (ch = getchar() == 'off') {
        printf("1 and off");
    }
      }
     else if (c = getchar() == 2) {
       if (ch = getchar() == 'on') {
         printf("2 and on");
}
        if (ch = getchar() == 'off') {
        printf("2 and off");
}
  }
    else {
      printf("break\n");
      break;
  }

}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to enable all warnings and debug info when compiling (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve your code to get no warnings. Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `if (c = getchar() == 2)` is wrong for several reasons. Perhaps you want something like `if ((c = getchar()) == '2')`

Answer (score 1):

[`getchar()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) and [fgetc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns a single `int` (containing the bytecode of a single character, or `EOF` on failure), which cannot be compared to the strings "on" or "off". Use [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) or [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, and use [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) when comparing strings, not `==`.

Comment: Note `'on'` is not a string, but a rarely used multi-character _integer character constant_ and can be compared to a single character -even if it is not really what OP needs.

Comment: BTW, on current computers [UTF-8 is used everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/). This adds some complexity (e.g. when the user types `µ` or `é` or `°` ....)

Answer (score -1):

Few obvious errors in your code @Mohan.

1. `c` is declared as an `integer` and you have used `getchar` to accept it from user, instead use `%d` with `scanf`.
2. `ch` is declared as a `char` when you need it to be `string` as it should hold more than 1 character. So make it a `char[]`.

I have given the code which would perfectly as you would need:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    printf("start\n");
    int c;
    char ch[10];
    int light_id = 1;
    //char on_off_str;
    while (light_id > 0) {

      printf("\nEnter number and on/off_str:\n");
      scanf("%d%s",&c,ch);
      if (c == 1) {
        if (strcmp(ch,"on") == 0)  {
          printf("\n1 and on");
        }
        else if (strcmp(ch,"off") == 0) {
         printf("\n1 and off");
        }
      }
      else if (c == 2) {
        if (strcmp(ch,"on") == 0) {
          printf("\n2 and on");
        }
        else if (strcmp(ch,"off") == 0) {
          printf("\n2 and off");
        }
      }
      else if((c!=1)&&(c!=2)) {
        printf("break\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your program do if user enters `a` for the number? You get Undefined Behavior... What I mean is, always check return code of `scanf`, especially in code you mean for others to learn from. The crude version is just this: `if(scanf("%d%s",&c,ch) != 2) return EXIT_FAILURE;`. Also, what's the deal with `light_id` condition?

Comment: I understand your point @Hyde. but this is what SO has coded. I don't know what he intends to do with it, or what handling mechanisms he plans on using in case of the unexpected inputs.

Comment: I didn't want to change the entire structure of the program, hence did what he just wanted to be done. nothing more, nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

From the inside out:

Strings are written in quotation marks `""` not in hyphons`''` these are for single characters.

`if (ch = getchar() == 'on')` is evaluating `getchar() == 'on'` first and the result gets written into `ch`. This happens because `==` has a higher precedence than `=`. To avoid such things use brackets.

If you want to compare strings you should use [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare strings.
Chars can be compared with `==` though.

If you want to create a safe program for reading strings, [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is the way to go. You can control how many characters you want to read into your char array and afterwards you can parse it with [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to your liking. A big advantage is that it consume everything in the input stream (including the newline), giving you full flexibility how to handle it. This is especially useful when reading from a file.

And on a sidenote: I would encourage you to format your code properly and compile with all warnings enabled

To give an example for your progam:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 50
int main(void)
{

    printf("start\n");
    long c = 0;
    char ch[5] = {0}, buf[BUFFER_SIZE]={0};
    char *loc;
    int light_id = 1;
    char found = 0;


    while (light_id > 0)
    {
        c= 0;
        printf("Enter number and on/off_str:\n");
        if (NULL == fgets(buf,BUFFER_SIZE,stdin))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        loc = buf;
        found = 0;

        //look for the first number in the string and convert it to long
        while (!found && *loc!=0 )
        {
            if (isdigit(*loc))
            {
                c = strtol(loc,&loc,10);
                found = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                loc++;
            }
        }

        while ( NULL == strchr(buf,'\n')) //check that everything until a newline is consumed
        {
            if (NULL == fgets(buf,BUFFER_SIZE,stdin))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (NULL == fgets(buf,BUFFER_SIZE,stdin))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        strncpy(ch,buf,4); //copy a string of max 4 chars into ch, leaving the 0 at the end.

        //terminate string on new line
        loc = strchr(ch,'\n');
        if (NULL != loc)
            *loc = 0;

        if (c == 1)
        {
            if (!strcmp("on",ch)) //strcmp returns 0 when strings are equal and the is \n is appended as it is not filtered out before hand
            {
                printf("1 and on\n");
            }
            if (!strcmp("off",ch))
            {
                printf("1 and off\n");
            }
        }
        else if (c == 2)
        {
            if (!strcmp("on",ch))
            {
                printf("2 and on\n");
            }
            if (!strcmp("off",ch))
            {
                printf("2 and off\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("break\n");
            light_id = 0; //break is not needed here as we already are at the end of the loop
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The next step would be to parse the read string in `ch` so you get correct results even if someone enters "on " or something like that.

Comment: What does your program do if user enters `a` for the number? You get Undefined Behavior... What I mean is, always check return code of `scanf`, especially in code you mean for others to learn from. The crude version is just this: `if(scanf("%d ",&c) != 1) return EXIT_FAILURE;`. Also, what's the deal with `light_id` condition?

Comment: @hyde I just checked and I can not find anything saying it is UB, I only found "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined." But this would mean that `%w` is undefined behaviour not entering `a` for `%d` it would just consume anything and then fail. At least that is what I understood

Comment: In this code, `c` will be uninitialized if `scanf` returns <1. Using `c` will be UB in that case.

Comment: Another way to fix the UB would be to initialize `c` before `scanf`, though I personally think it's much better to check for IO errors explicitly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180434/discussion-between-kami-kaze-and-hyde).